# Angular directive to swap ng-click function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an app where a person can build lists of 'favorites.' On the page for a particular item there is a button that you can click to add the item to your list of favorites.

What I would like to happen is: Click the button, item is added to favorites, now the button is a different color and if you were to click it again it would remove the item from your favorites.

I think it would be best to build a directive to handle this but I am completely lost.

In my html I have:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite" ng-click="addFavorite(item.id)">
<md-icon md-svg-icon="heart"></md-icon></md-button>
```

My addFavorite and deleteFavorite functions work correctly, but I can't figure out how to toggle which one happens and how to update that after the request fires.

Comment: you haven't shown the `deleteFavorite` here, but this sounds trivial with the use of `ng-if`.

Comment: Can ng-if update the view when the response is received from the Api?

Comment: as long as the variable the `ng-if` is monitoring is two way bound, it will react whenever the variable changes....

Comment: also, the posted answer brings up a good point, you could have a single function that performs both actions, and just change the styling on the button.

Answer (score 0):

So lets address a few different things.

1. Most likely this is going to be a div styled to look like a button to achieve the effect you want.  You could go the easy route and use http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#buttons  or something else.  Styling buttons is just not going to be the best cross browser support.
2. You could do this entirely with ng-class in a directive, some example code below. Assuming you are using bootstrap.  This just becomes what class do you want to change it to kinda thing. Below I have used an icon but the principal is the same.

**Directive**

> ```
> .directive('toggleClass', function() {
>     return {
>         restrict: 'A',
>         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
>             element.bind('click', function() {
>                 if(element.attr("class") == "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil") {
>                     element.removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-pencil");
>                     element.addClass(attrs.toggleClass);
>                     addFavorite(element.id);
>                 } else {
>                     element.removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
>                     element.addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-pencil");
>                     removeFavorite(element.id);
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     };
> });
> ```

**Template**

`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" toggle-class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>`

Comment: I'm actually using angular material design. I think the class of the button will not be the hardest part, but switching the button's functionality is where I'm stuck. Also updating it when the response comes back from the Api.

Comment: The same logic applies, since you are checking to see if a button has the specific class you then can determine what action it will take.  You are basically using the elements current class to decide what to do.

Comment: So like addFavorite(element.id); would be in one of them and removeFavorite(element.id); would be in the other,  since you have a directive you can build that logic in.

Comment: @Natalie do you need anything else with this?